# Reactor - Change flatMap Concurrency Dynamically

Tags: spring, spring-boot, project-reactor, reactive-streams, spring-webclient

Is it possible to change the Reactor Flux flatMap concurrency during runtime?

The [flatMap](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-int-) API allows us to configure the concurrency during the assembly time.

I am using flatMap to subscribe to a WebClient, the WebClient does a GET of REST call to external service. During runtime, I may get into issue such as Rate Limits, Service Not available, Internal server errors, In that case I would like to set the concurrency as low as 1 to reduce the amount of in processing elements. When things are back to normal, I would like to bring the concurrency to optimal level again.

Comment: Have you looked at the [retry methods](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#retryWhen-reactor.util.retry.Retry-) available? Do they fit your use case?

Comment: Yes! I am using retry method in WebClient to retry when internal server and bad gateway issues happens. But when WebClient gets into retry mode, I need to slow down my entire operation.

Comment: I think you can't change concurrency at runtime but you might control the slow down part. Expanding a bit on Michael's comment you might look into retry with backoff: https://projectreactor.io/docs/extra/release/api/reactor/retry/Retry.html This gives you an option to introduce some potentially random or increasing delay when error happens.

Comment: As @MartinTarjányi said, have a look at `retryWhen(Retry.backoff())` which will likely give a better fit to what you need rather than adjusting concurrency.